# Jquery Kwicks Expand Panel By Onselect Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid, kwicks

I have a menu with a dropdown select!

```
<select name="category" id="category" required><option value="0">Choose</option><button type="button" onclick="javascript:formsubmit();">Keres</button>
```

And go on with the value. I have a kwicks panel with this:

```
    <div class='kwicks kwicks-horizontal'>
<a href='#' id='kwick1' onclick="javascript:playerrl(1);"></a>
<a href='#' id='kwick2' onclick="javascript:playerrl(2);"></a>
<a href='#' id='kwick3' onclick="javascript:playerrl(3);"></a>
<a href='#' id='kwick4' onclick="javascript:playerrl(4);"></a>
<a href='#' id='kwick5' onclick="javascript:playerrl(5);"></a>
<a href='#' id='kwick6' onclick="javascript:playerrl(6);"></a>
<a href='#' id='kwick7' onclick="javascript:playerrl(7);"></a>
</div>
```

And I have an javascript event on my form with my select menu:

```
                   <script>
                      function formsubmit(){
                      var cat = document.getElementById("category").value;
                      var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
                      var iframe = document.getElementById("player");
                      $(container).kwicks('expand', cat);
                      iframe.src = "video/index.php?keres="+search+"&category="+cat;
                      }
                      </script>
```

It checks the selected value, changes the iframe src and what not working now is expanding the kwicks panel with the selected value! Firebug says:

```
ReferenceError: container is not defined
```

But it is in kwicks.js! Why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`container` is undefined because you haven't declared it anywhere.  Judging from your code it looks like what you need to have is

`$('.kwicks').kwicks('expand', cat);`

... assuming that `cat` is going to be a valid panel index.

---

Edit: also, did you paste all of your `<select>` markup? What you've pasted isn't valid markup as the `<select>` isn't closed.